# How to check if Dictionary of type class can be verified using ContainValue in Fluent Assertion

Tags: c#, assertions, fluent-assertions

I am trying to check Dictionary of type custom class as Value.

I would like to know if my approach of searching for value within Dictionary is correct using ContainValue in Fluent Assertion.

Here is the code

```
    public static void VerifyDictionary()
    {
        try
        {
            Dictionary<int, Employee> empDict = new Dictionary<int, Employee>
            {
                { 1, new Employee() {EmployeeID = 100,Name="Karthik", EmployeeEmail="karthik@executeautomation.com", EmployeeAddress="Chennai,India"}},
                {2, new Employee() { EmployeeID = 101,Name="Jack",EmployeeEmail="Jack@jill.com",EmployeeAddress="CA"} },
                {3, new Employee() { EmployeeID=102,Name="Sam",EmployeeEmail="Sam@sung.com",EmployeeAddress="SFO"}},
                {4, new Employee() { EmployeeID=103,Name="Max",EmployeeEmail="micro@max.com",EmployeeAddress="India" }}
            };

            empDict.Should().ContainValue(new Employee() { EmployeeID = 10, EmployeeEmail = "micro@max.com", EmployeeAddress = "India", Name = "Max" }, "because thats the information I need");


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Employee Class

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeEmail { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeAddress { get; set; }
}
```

While I execute this code, I am getting exception as shown

**

```
Expected dictionary {[1, BDDDemo.Employee], [2, BDDDemo.Employee], [3, BDDDemo.Employee], [4, BDDDemo.Employee]} to contain value 
BDDDemo.Employee
{
   EmployeeAddress = "India"
   EmployeeEmail = "micro@max.com"
   EmployeeID = 10
   Name = "Max"
} because thats the information I need.
```

**

Please help me understand whats wrong I am doing here.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you using Fluent Assertion in some context outside of Unit Testing?  I ask because with a unit testing framework traditionally you wouldn't catch the exception but would instead let the Test Runner handle it as a failure.

Comment: @vossad01- Actually I am running fluent assertion in normal C# console application project, I am not using any test framework like MSTest or NUnit here. Just to see if the Fluent Assertion really works for my needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ContainValue`'s check for whether a value is in the dictionary or not is based on the `Equals` method of values in the dictionary.

In this case `Employee` does not override `Equals` so the implementation inherited from Object is used; that is reference equality will be used.

As an example, the following code would pass:

```cs
var expected = new Employee { EmployeeID = 10 };
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, Employee> { {1, expected} };
dictionary.Should().ContainValue( expected );
```

This, however, would fail because they are two different instances of `Employee` even though all their members are the same:

```cs
var expected = new Employee { EmployeeID = 10 };
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, Employee> { {1, expected} };
dictionary.Should().ContainValue( new Employee { EmployeeID = 10 } );
```

To make this later case pass you could override `Equals`.  However, the entire class is mutable so I cannot recommend that unless you also make whichever member(s) you are using to determine Equality immutable.

Without modifying the class, your best bet is to use a different assertion, probably along these lines:

```cs
dictionary.Values.Should().Contain(employee => 
    /* Logic for how you want to determine a match */);
```

Comment: Thank you so much Vossad01, The approach `empDict.Values.Should().Contain(a => a.EmployeeID == 102);` worked fine. Instead of dictionary I replaced that to empDict (I know thats what you meant). The answer was very explanatory and helped me a lot. Thanks a ton !!!